# mutate_at - using a function with map2

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

My objective is to convert a set monthly revenue columns from AUD to USD. To achieve this, I need to apply a different exchange rate to each of the revenue columns.

data for analysis:

```
pacman::p_load(lubridate, purrr, dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
        Date     = seq(dmy("01/01/2017"), by = "day", length.out = 3),

        Customer = "a",
        Product  =  "xxx",
        Revenue1  = c(10, 20, 30),
        Revenue2  = c(100, 200, 300))

df2 <- data.frame(Factor1 = c(10),
                  Factor2 = c(20))

df3 <- select(df1, Revenue1:Revenue2)
```

This is my function

```
fx_adjust <- function(x, y = df2){map2_df(x, y, ~ .x * .y)}
```

These two work:

```
fx_adjust(df3, df2)
mutate_at(df1, vars(contains("Revenue")), funs(. * 10))
```

But this does not work:

```
mutate_at(df1, vars(contains("Revenue")), funs(fx_adjust(.)))
```

Could someone kindly explain why `mutate_at` is misbehaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `mutate_at` calls your function separately for each column. It does not pass all the columns at once in the `.`

Observe this example

```
fx_dump<-function(...) print(list(...))
mutate_at(df1, vars(contains("Revenue")), funs(fx_dump(.)))
```

You'll see that `fx_dump` is called twice, once for each column. You cannot pass multiple parameters at a time to your function using `mutate_at`.

Comment: The problems sounds like your data isn't "tidy." I'd probably reshape so you don't have multiple revenue columns then it would be easier to do a standard join to make modifications.

Comment: unfortunately, my data is a few gigs and when I "gather" the revenue then join the monthly Fx rate, "mutate" then try to "spread", the machine runs out of memory. Hence, the above strategy.

Comment: If you do want to pass in a .x and .y to mutate() I made an experimental function pairwise() for doing such (that works like across() but takes in the pairs of .x and .y columns). Can install it via instructions here: https://github.com/brshallo/pwiser